# How to connect to Oracle Cloud Database with instant client from CentOS 7?

Tags: database, oracle, ssl-certificate, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracleclient

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Cloud Database using the instant client from a CentOS 7 machine.

I created the databases in the OCI interface, I downloaded the wallet files and created one user with the DWROLE role.

I installed the bellow packages on the system

```
oracle-instantclient19.8-basic-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient19.8-devel-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient19.8-sqlplus-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient19.8-tools-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I created set the bellow folders and set the env vars

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.8/client64
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

then I unzipped the wallet files to `TNS_ADMIN`

```
[root@workvm admin]# ll
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6733 Sep 17  2020 cwallet.sso
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6688 Sep 17  2020 ewallet.p12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3276 Sep 17  2020 keystore.jks
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  691 Sep 17  2020 ojdbc.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  317 Sep 17  2020 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  114 Sep 17  2020 sqlnet.ora
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1813 Sep 16 14:18 tnsnames.ora
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3336 Sep 17  2020 truststore.jks
[root@workvm admin]# pwd
/usr/lib/oracle/19.8/client64/network/admin
```

The `tnsnames.ora` files have some autogenerated services defined

```
otakudb_high = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=...)
otakudb_low = (...)
otakudb_medium = (...)
```

According to what I have read, I should be able to connect to the database by executing

```
sqlplus metalbob@otakudb_high
```

However, when I run it the connection halts and then errors out with the following message

```
[donhk@workvm ~]$ sqlplus metalbob@otakudb_high

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 16 14:01:52 2020
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter password:
ERROR: ORA-28791: certificate verification failure

[donhk@workvm ~]$
```

What is the correct procedure to connect to the remote database?

**Edit after Joe answer:**

This is how my `sqlnet.ora` file was prior to the changes

```
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="?/network/admin")))
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=yes
```

**This is how I changed to make it work after joe answer**

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES)
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="?/network/admin")))
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=yes
```

There is no need to change the `DIRECTORY`, the trick was this

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES)
```

Hope this helps someone!

**Edit 2**

I realized that after I bounced the machine, I was able to connect, maybe it was a network problem on the machine or a library not properly loaded

Comment: There's no reason not to use EZ Connect.  In fact the syntax was extended precisely for cloud use, see the tech article [Oracle Database 19c Easy Connect Plus Configurable Database Connection
Syntax](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-19c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf).

Comment: Do you have some other sqlnet.ora files that are also being read and that set directory_path to something else?

Comment: I don't recall where on the 1k tabs I open I read about the ezconnect, glad you clarified it, I will update the question to prevent spreading lies on stackoveflow, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this up last week in [How to connect to Oracle Autonomous Cloud Databases](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases).

You can edit sqlnet.ora if you don't have the config files in the default `network/admin` directory.  If they are in that directory then you don't need to edit it, because the pre-supplied path `"?/network/admin"` maps to the `network/admin` subdirectory under where the `libclntsh.so` file is.

The other alternative is to use "Easy Connect Plus" syntax like:

```
tcps://adb.ap-sydney-1.oraclecloud.com:1522/abc_cjjson_high.adb.oraclecloud.com?wallet_location=/Users/cjones/Cloud/CJJSON
```

Extract `cwallet.so` from the wallet zip, and stick it in a directory (I used `/Users/cjones/Cloud/CJJSON`).  Then find the host, servicename, port etc from the wallet tnsnames.ora file and build up your easy connect string.  Then you can 'throw away' the zip file since it is not needed :)

Comment: I removed the `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH` from the sqlnet.ora and it still connects, now I'm puzzled since the files are unchanged, and they work now but they were exactly the same before and they did not work, I think when I restarted the machine something got updated somewhere, could that be the case?

Comment: Do you have any other sqlnet.ora or ~/.sqlnet.ora files around?